# Finding spot size experimentally

Tags: optics

I am not a specialist in optics so I needed a big help, I'm doing this experiment where I am using a blue laser diode PLTB450B which is collimated using a G2 lens, now my question is how to find the spot size of the beam experimentally? As I need to produce a small spot and then use a flurosence in that position to produce a white light

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_measure_the_spot_size_of_the_laser_focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the *knife-edge* method. The idea is to measure the total power in the beam after part of it is clipped by a knife edge. By doing so one can relate the power measurement with the position of the knife edge in the beam. For a Gaussian beam the curve would be an error-function and its scale would give the width of the Gaussian.

Comment: One would also likely want to do this along two orthogonal directions to check if it is symmetric or not.